# How to declare click listener within RecyclerView adapter declaration inside Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-adapter

I'm trying to connect my Activity (containing a `RecyclerView`) with a `RecyclerView` adapter but got stuck at the declaration part. I understand that a value associated with the click listener parameter in my adapter class needs to be specified but I'm unsure of what it should be when each RecyclerView item has a different value.

```
mAdapter = MyAdapter(this, mList, true, ?)
```

Any ideas on what the question should mark be replaced with?

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mAdapter: MyAdapter
    private val mList = ArrayList<MyItem>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mList.add(
                ItemCompany(
                        getString(R.string.bing)
                )
        )
        mList.add(
                ItemCompany(
                        getString(R.string.google)
                )
        )
        mList.add(
                ItemCompany(
                        getString(R.string.yahoo)
                )
        )

        val mRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.myRecyclerView)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager =
                        androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mAdapter = MyAdapter(this, mList, true, ?)
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                        androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration(
                                this,
                                LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                        )
                )
        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView adapter**

```
class MyAdapter(
        val myContext: Context,
        var listCompany: MutableList<ItemCompany>,
        private val mTwoPane: Boolean,
        private val itemClickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter
.CompanyViewHolder>() {

    class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_RVItem)

        fun bind(company: ItemCompany, clickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)
        {
            tvTitle.text = company.companyName

            itemView.setOnClickListener {v ->
                val intent: Intent = when (company.companyName) {
                    v.resources.getString(R.string.bing) -> {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://www.bing.com/"))
                    }
                    v.resources.getString(R.string.google) -> {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"))
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("https://www.yahoo.com/"))
                    }
                }
                itemView.getContext.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CompanyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(myContext)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false)
        return CompanyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CompanyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = listCompany[holder.adapterPosition]

        holder.tvTitle.text = product.companyName

        holder.bind(product, itemClickListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listCompany.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return companyFilter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either declare your click listener with a lamda:

```
val mListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> }
val mAdapter = MyAdapter(this, mList, true, mListener)
```

Or simply:

```
val mAdapter = MyAdapter(this, mList, true) { parent, view, position, id -> }
```